# Error comparando 2 arrays

Tags: php, array

Tengo una app que me regresa dos arrays de objetos el primero lo obtiene de un API y el segundo de mi base de datos, lo que quiero hacer es comparar el segundo array con el primero y que me muestre los elementos que no se encuentran en el segundo array.

Esto es lo que hice pero no estoy recibiendo el resultado esperado.

```
    $devices1 = [
        {"id":281252492,"name":"Android Panel","product":"Android Panel","version":"10.6.7","lastSeenAt":"Last seen: 2019-06-09"},
        {"id":281258555,"name":"ONEPLUS A5000","product":"Android","version":"7.16.0.10517","lastSeenAt":"Last seen: 2019-06-08"},
        {"id":281258334,"name":"Galaxy S7","product":"Android","version":"7.16.1.10610","lastSeenAt":"Last seen: 2019-06-08"},
        {"id":281257970,"name":"Chrome","product":"Plataforma Web","version":"3.102.0","lastSeenAt":"Last seen: 2019-06-08"},
        {"id":281256712,"name":"herr","product":"Android","version":"7.16.1.10610","lastSeenAt":"Last seen: 2019-06-08"},
        {"id":275309414,"name":"Firefox","product":"Plataforma Web","version":"3.102.0","lastSeenAt":"Last seen: 2019-06-08"}
    ];

$devices2 = [
        {"_id":"5cfc14bd32ca560017c8f2e1","cuenta":"48-1-PHQ7PVBR","idDevice":"281258334","deviceName":"Galaxy S7","product":"Android","idUsuario":{"_id":"5cfbc901a0e3d1001774985e","nombre":"fussion"},"idServerAccount":"5cfc0de532ca560017c8f2e0","dealerId":"48","dealerName":"root","__v":0},
        {"_id":"5cfc14f832ca560017c8f2e2","cuenta":"48-1-NRNF7MRM","idDevice":"281258555","deviceName":"ONEPLUS A5000","product":"Android","idUsuario":{"_id":"5cfbc901a0e3d1001774985e","nombre":"fussion"},"idServerAccount":"5cfc0de532ca560017c8f2e0","dealerId":"48","dealerName":"root","__v":0}
    ];

foreach($devices1 as $device1){

    if ($device1->name == 'Android Panel' || $device1->product == 'Plataforma Web') {
        continue;
    }

    $encontrado = false;

    foreach ($devices2 as $device2) {

        if ($device2->idDevice == $device1->id) {

            $encontrado = true;
            return $encontrado;

        }       

    }

    if ($encontrado == false) {

        echo 'Dispositivo identificado ID: '.$device1->id.' | '.$device1->name.' | '.$device1->product.'<br>';          

    }   

}
```

Necesito que filtre los `devices` con nombre `Android Panel` o que el producto sea `Plataforma web` y me imprima en pantalla los dispositivos que no estan en el segundo array.

En este caso seria el device con id: 281256712

Comment: No seria `$device2->_id == $device1->id ` ?

Comment: no por que en el arreglo de $device2 la propiedad que quiero comparar es idDevice contra la propiedad id del array $device1

Comment: cierto, fallo mio que no lo había visto

Comment: Te sale algún error? No visualizas nada ?

Answer (score 2):

Te planteo otra solucion para enfocar el problema con las funciones que te ofrece php. Vamos por partes:

**Primero:** el formato de definicion de los dispositivos que pones, no es correcto en php. Voy a suponer que es la cadena json que representa esos dispositivos, por lo que primero tienes que cambiarlos a objeto php:

```
   $devices1 = '[
        {"id":281252492,"name":"Android Panel","product":"Android Panel","version":"10.6.7","lastSeenAt":"Last seen: 2019-06-09"},
        {"id":281258555,"name":"ONEPLUS A5000","product":"Android","version":"7.16.0.10517","lastSeenAt":"Last seen: 2019-06-08"},
        {"id":281258334,"name":"Galaxy S7","product":"Android","version":"7.16.1.10610","lastSeenAt":"Last seen: 2019-06-08"},
        {"id":281257970,"name":"Chrome","product":"Plataforma Web","version":"3.102.0","lastSeenAt":"Last seen: 2019-06-08"},
        {"id":281256712,"name":"herr","product":"Android","version":"7.16.1.10610","lastSeenAt":"Last seen: 2019-06-08"},
        {"id":275309414,"name":"Firefox","product":"Plataforma Web","version":"3.102.0","lastSeenAt":"Last seen: 2019-06-08"}
    ]';

$devices2 = '[
        {"_id":"5cfc14bd32ca560017c8f2e1","cuenta":"48-1-PHQ7PVBR","idDevice":"281258334","deviceName":"Galaxy S7","product":"Android","idUsuario":{"_id":"5cfbc901a0e3d1001774985e","nombre":"fussion"},"idServerAccount":"5cfc0de532ca560017c8f2e0","dealerId":"48","dealerName":"root","__v":0},
        {"_id":"5cfc14f832ca560017c8f2e2","cuenta":"48-1-NRNF7MRM","idDevice":"281258555","deviceName":"ONEPLUS A5000","product":"Android","idUsuario":{"_id":"5cfbc901a0e3d1001774985e","nombre":"fussion"},"idServerAccount":"5cfc0de532ca560017c8f2e0","dealerId":"48","dealerName":"root","__v":0}
    ]';

$devices1=json_decode($devices1, true);
$devices2=json_decode($devices2, true);
```

ahora si, tenemos "arrays" php :)

Vamos a filtrar los dispositivos 1, porque te interesan cojer los que son de `android panel` o que son de `plataforma web`. Para ello, voy a utilizar array_filter:

```
$list_tmp = array_filter($devices1, function($v) {
  return ($v['name'] == 'Android Panel' || $v["product"]== 'Plataforma Web');
});
```

Como lo que quieres es comparar los ids, quizas es mejor filtrar esos campos para hacer luego la comparacion. Voy a cojer solo la columna id (o la idDevice) que son las que utilizaremos para la comparacion:

```
$list1 = array_column($list_tmp, "id");
$list2 = array_column($devices2, "idDevice");
```

en $list1 tienes los elementos filtrados y solo con el campo id de los devices1, y en $list2 tienes los id de devices2.

Nos queda buscar la diferencia entre los arrays, por lo que puedes usar `array_diff`:

```
$result = array_diff($list1, $list2);
```

En $result tienes los id de devices1 que no estan en devices2.

Si haces un printf a las variables:

```
print_r($list1);
print_r($list2);

print_r($result);
```

Veras el resultado siguiente:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 281252492
    [1] => 281257970
    [2] => 275309414
)


Array
(
    [0] => 281258334
    [1] => 281258555
)


Array
(
    [0] => 281252492
    [1] => 281257970
    [2] => 275309414
)
```

Esto nos puede indicar que el resultado `281256712`no es el que debe salir (ya que es un `android`, no un `android panel`), sino `281252492`, `281257970` y `275309414`, puesto que:

```
281252492 -> es un Android Panel
281257970 -> es plataforma web
275309414 -> es plataforma web
```

y ninguno de ellos esta en el devices2 original