# Comparar dos arrays con array_intersect

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo dos arrays, devueltos de dos consultas a la base de datos.

Consultas:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "select email from sec_users where control = 0 and active = 'Y'");
$compVacaciones = mysqli_query($link, "select email from solicitud as s inner join sec_users as u on u.login = s.fk_empleado where ("2019-06-12" between date(s.fecha_inicio) and date(s.fecha_fin)) and fk_estado_sup = 1 group by s.fk_empleado");

$control = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$vacaciones = mysqli_fetch_array($compVacaciones);
```

Lo que intento es comparar los dos arrays y que si en el array `$control` encuentra algún resultado del array `$vacaciones` pues que desaparezcan del array `$control`. He intentado hacer una prueba con `array_intersect()` y que me devuelva en un `print_r()` lo que deseo eliminar del array `$control`, pero no me ha funcionado.

```
$resultado = array_intersect($control, $vacaciones);
print_r($resultado);
```

¿Alguna ayuda con lo que deseo hacer?

Comment: puedes publicar el resultado de los print_r de $control y $vacaciones, para ver como son tus arrays?. Podria ser un duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/270809/error-comparando-2-arrays/270874#270874?

Comment: ¿Por qué no haces la intersección directamente en la base de datos?

Comment: @David ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: me da que en lugar de array_intersect lo que quieres es un `array_diff` (por eso lo del posible duplicado). Ya que quieres la diferencia entre los correos de `$vacaciones` y los de `$control`

Comment: Modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es la función `array_diff`. Lo que hace es buscar el contenido del primer `array` dentro del segundo y devolverte los resultados que no haya encontrado.

```
$frutas = ['banana', 'fresa', 'naranja', 'manzana'];
$frutas2 = ['fresa', 'manzana'];

$resultado = array_diff($frutas, $frutas2);

print_r($resultado);
```

**Resultado**

```
Array ( [0] => banana [2] => naranja )
```

**Referencia:** [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff.php)

Comment: Me devuelve el siguiente error: Warning: array_diff(): Argument #2 is not an array

Comment: Si la estructura de los `array` es diferente no te va a funcionar. Vas a tener que subirnos el `print_r` de `$control` y de `$vacaciones` como te pide el colega @Jakala.

Comment: Ya he visto el fallo, sin querer había modificado una de mis consultas. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 2):

El método que buscas, es `array_diff()`, el cuál retorna aquellos valores del primer array que no estén presentes en el segundo. El código sería algo así:

```
$resultado = array_diff($control, $vacaciones);
```

Te dejo también la documentación de la [función](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff.php).

Comment: Me devuelve el siguiente error: Warning: array_diff(): Argument #2 is not an array

Comment: Ya he visto el fallo, sin querer había modificado una de mis consultas. Muchas gracias por la ayuda!