# array_diff() solo me devuelve un dato

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo dos arrays que los creo a través de dos consultas:

Consulta 1:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "select email from sec_users where control = 0 and active = 'Y'");
```

Devuelve:

```
admin@admin.com, usuario@usuario.com, usuario1@usuario.com, usuario2@usuario.com
```

Consulta 2:

```
$compVacaciones = mysqli_query($link, "select email from solicitud as s inner join sec_users as u on u.login = s.fk_empleado where ('2019-06-12' between date(s.fecha_inicio) and date(s.fecha_fin)) group by s.fk_empleado");
```

Devuelve:

```
admin@admin.com, usuario1@usuario.com
```

Quiero que `array_diff()` me devuelva un array con las diferencias entre los dos arrays. Por ejemplo en este caso me debe devolver:

```
usuario@usuario.com, usuario2@usuario.com
```

Este es mi código:

```
while ($control = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  while ($vacaciones = mysqli_fetch_array($compVacaciones)) {
    $resultado = array_diff($control, $vacaciones);
    print_r($resultado);
  };
};
```

Pero solo me devuelve un solo `email`. Osea, el primero de la lista
¿Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Estas pasando variables no arrays por eso el warning.

Comment: @JDev ¿Cómo debería pasarlos?

Comment: Lo que tendrias que hacer es almacenar todos los valores en 2 variables tipo array (una para cada consulta) y luego si usar el `array_intersect` sobre esas 2 variables.

Comment: @JDev Perdón, he editado la pregunta porque estaba mal planteada

Comment: ¿Cuantos datos devuelve cada query?

Comment: @JDev Espera, lo edito de nuevo con los resultados de cada query

Comment: posible duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/270809/error-comparando-2-arrays/270874#270874. Siguiendo el mismo ejemplo puedes cojer todos los datos en dos arrays y hacer el array_dif

Comment: @JDev Ya está editada la pregunta

Comment: @Jakala No es un duplicado. Como ves no son los mismos datos, además esa pregunta que me mandas no está ni solucionada

Comment: Es por culpa de como lo tienes montado, cada vez que llamas a `array_diff` le pasas un unico elemento por array por lo que el resultado va a tener entre 0 y 1 resultados. Tienes que hacerlo como te digo, primero recuperas los resultados de las querys en 2 variables de tipo array y luego si haces el `array_diff`

Comment: considero que es duplicado, porque se trata del mismo ejemplo. dos arrays con ciertos elementos repetidos, y calculado la diferencia entre ellos. Ademas, si tiene solucion (de hecho la he puesto yo)

Comment: @JDev Puede ponerme una respuesta en la pregunta de como debería hacerlo?

Comment: la respuesta la tienes en el enlace anterior. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/270809/error-comparando-2-arrays/270874#270874. De todas formas, la cosa es que no tienes que usar el `array_diff` dentro de los bucles. Usa cada bucle separado para obtener cada array, y luego utiliza el array_diff con esos arrays resultantes.